# Trying to access OWA via http://servername/ forwards to https://webmail.domain.com/owa... Where is this configured?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

Basically my issue is spelled out in the title... I'm trying to enable access to OWA for internal users via the server name directly, which worked fine when we had Exchange 2003, but with my Exchange 2010 server it's being forwarded to the URL specified above.  The OWA URL for external access is owa.domain.com/owa, so I'm not sure where it's getting this webmail prefix from... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It comes from the internal URL set in the OWA settings in Exchange (OWA-VirtualDirectory settings in PS/IIS).

Comment: Okay, where in IIS Manager do I administrate this?  I'm looking at the virtual directory, but not sure which setting I'm looking for...

Comment: What happens if you browse to https:// servername/ ? I wonder if it requires SSL, and redirects to https:// webmail.domain.com/owa in response to a 403 (403.4 - SSL required) error. (struggling with formatting, sorry)

Comment: Jeremy, I get a "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" page, and if I continue, I get the IIS7 splash page (Welcome, Bienvenido, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Inside the EMC, under `Server Configuration`, `Client Access`, click on the `Outlook Web App` tab, and then open the properties for the OWA (default web site).

Change the internal URL to whatever it should be.

Comment: The Internal URL here is set to https://servername.domain.com/...

Comment: In Exchange shell, `get-owaVirtualDirectory | fl name,internalURL,externalURL` what shows up?

Comment: Name: owa (Default Web Site)
InternalURL: http://servername.domain.com/
ExternalURL: https://owa.domain.com/owa

Comment: k, in DNS is "servername" an a record or a CNAME to "webmail"?

Comment: TheCleaner, "webmail" doesn't appear anywhere in DNS.

Comment: but it works/resolves/shows a page?  How is it resolving webmail.domain.com then if not in DNS?  Also, have you checked in IIS on the server for redirection?  If you are typing only http://servername then it would be under the default site in IIS.

Comment: As of right now it looks like neither webmail.domain.com or servername.domain.com will resolve...  https does though.

Comment: Short of "hire someone to look at it with you", look at the redirect options here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998359%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx , but it doesn't make sense that https://servername resolves but non-ssl doesn't...DNS is DNS.  Now it might not be listening on port 80, but still look at the link and if you need more help you'll need to edit your OP and include screenshots, attempted solutions, etc. to see what you are seeing.